# problem with integration and plot

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration

I have a problem with the following function, I want to integrate my function on r for r between 0 and infinity and then plot it, but I can't compute it, I get the following error...

> Integrate::ilim: Invalid integration variable or limit(s) in {3,0,[Infinity]}.
>   NIntegrate::itraw: Raw object 3 cannot be used as an iterator.

Here my code,

```
mu0 = 4*Pi*10^(-7)
Ms = 0.0926/mu0 
bH = 2.91*10^8 
R = 4
(*Function*)
Heff[q_, A_, Hi_] := (Hi/mu0 + 2*A/(Ms*mu0)*(q*10^(10))^2) 
p[q_, A_, Hi_] := Ms/Heff[q, A, Hi]
Vp[r_] := 4/3*Pi*(r*10^(-9))^3 
FF[q_, r_] := 9*SphericalBesselJ[1, q*10^(10)*r*10^(-9)]^2/(q*10^(10)*r*10^(-9))^2 
RH[q_, A_, Hi_] := (1/4)*p[q, A, Hi]^2*(2 + 1/(1 + p[q, A, Hi])^(0.5)) 
RM[q_, A_, Hi_] := ((1 + p[q, A, Hi])^(0.5) - 1)/2
Mz2[q_, dM_, r_] := ((dM/mu0)^2/(8*Pi)^3)*Vp[r]^2*FF[q, r];
h2[q_, Hp_, r_] := ((Hp/mu0)^2/(8^3*Pi^3))*Vp[r]^2*FF[q, r]; 


f[r_, C_, p_] := (1/(C*r*10^(-9)*p))*Exp[-(Log[r*10^(-9)] -Log[R*10^(-9)])^2/(2*p^2)]  

Sigma1[q_, A_, Hi_, dM_, Hp_, r_, C_, p_] := 
         Integrate[(Mz2[q, dM, r]*RM[q, A, Hi] + h2[q, Hp, r]*RH[q, A, Hi])*
           f[r, C, p], {r, 0, Infinity}]

p3 = Plot[
  Sigma1[q, 8.15*10^(-12), 0.5, 0.05, 0.030 , 3, 2, 0.14], {q, 0.001, 
   0.3},
  PlotRange -> All,
  ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log"},
  PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.0055], Black},
  AspectRatio -> 1,
  Frame -> True,
  FrameStyle -> Black,
  BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 20, FontFamily -> "Arial"}]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, I edited and added `f[r,C,p]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you evaluate a definite integral wrt a variable then that's it. You cannot use it in your function `Sigma1[q_, A_, Hi_, dM_, Hp_, r_, C_, p_]` . Remove it from here and its value in the plot then everything will be ok. I used `NIntegrate` for quick evaluation.

```
Sigma1[q_, A_, Hi_, dM_, Hp_, C_, p_] := 
     NIntegrate[(Mz2[q, dM, r]*RM[q, A, Hi] + h2[q, Hp, r]*RH[q, A, Hi])*
       f[r, C, p], {r, 0, Infinity}]

p3 = Plot[
  Sigma1[q, 8.15*10^(-12), 0.5, 0.05, 0.030, 2, 0.14], {q, 0.001, 
   0.3}, PlotRange -> All, ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log"}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.0055], Black}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
  Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Black, 
  BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 20, FontFamily -> "Arial"}]
```

[image]

Comment: I see, thanks a lot